# How to change the facebook ui feed size?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have included share button in my website. The share button works fine in web browsers.
But when access through mobile, after clicking the share button, the share popup size is same as web browser. So it is not getting displayed properly.

Can anyone please suggest, how to alter the height and width of the feed popup?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you cannot change the appearance and size of the popups made with FB.ui. You could try opening your own popup:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0

See "URL Redirection".

One other possibility is to use the "sharer.php", it is even easier to handle because you only need to add the URL as parameter and it will automatically get the Open Graph data from that URL.